# the voltage output and resistance of a potato

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistance, reference

For an undergrad lab experiment on noise analysis in various electric power suppliers, I constructed a battery from a potato with Cu/Zn electrodes and measured the outgoing voltage. Now I want an academic reference for the expected voltage from a potato and its resistance.

Is anyone familiar with something like this? I could only find this [paper](http://www.tau.ac.il/~agolberg/pdf/2010_3.pdf) but I didnt apply any external resistance on the potato so I'm not sure it is suitable for me.

Comment: Why don't you attach an external load? Measure the on load and off load voltage. The same way you would find a battery internal resistance...

Comment: @MCG I already have data, now I want to compare it to other studies

Comment: *the expected voltage from a potato* Let me fill you in on a little secret: the voltage you get from a battery also depends a lot on the materials you use for the electrodes. Note how a working potato battery needs electrodes of **different metals**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I've edited my question. I used Cu/Zn electrodes

Comment: "academic" and "undergrad lab" seem like a strange combination. There's nothing stopping you from doing the measurements yourself, you are in a lab, no?

Comment: A Cu/Zn cell should have an output of about 1.10V (https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/General_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/16%3A_Electrochemistry/24.02%3A_Galvanic_cells_and_Electrodes).  Its resistance is almost impossible to determine, since potatoes are highly variable.

Comment: Hardly an academic paper, but [Big Clive](https://youtu.be/sskSFYxzkpE) has a live demo of a mains powered potato. Real time current clamp numbers can give you resistance with some math.

Answer (score 3):

The open cell voltage, Voc for the boiled potato with Zn/Cu plates is **760mV** due to Reduction

- Zn+ 2H+ → Zn++ +  H2

### Extra Info

For any battery curve with a voltage, V vs current, I you can compute ;
- the slope or Effective Series Resistance, ΔV/ΔI=ESR[Ω]
- maximum power transfer (MPT) for pulse load (~50% Voc) for load ~ ESR
- maximum mWh or mAh vs load R usually for load >>ESR

Here the author plotted R load [kΩ] vs the inverse of current [1/mA]
[image]
In terms of energy cost mWh/$ which is more convenient than J/$, this can be extracted from the same curve of **μWh/cm² vs mVolt** by computing the ESR of the boiled potato. From P=V²/R estimate data values from plot into a spreadsheet.

- Then consider what is the optimum load from R=V²/P using the  plots [mV²]/ [μWh/cm²]

Using a spreadsheet I am sure you can work out the optimal load R for a given area and thickness of boiled spuds and make arrays to match the desired load for V=IR= Voc-I*ESR.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This may be good for 3rd world tropical countries that can grow potatoes cheaply AND it's bio-friendly.

Comment: What happens if you add in the energy / cost of boiling the potato? +1

Comment: I imagine they would have to burn garbage  wood and clean water outdoors in a big tank then of course labour must be free, academic optimism then there is disposal cost of rotten potatoes.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a chemistry question. Try googling "cell potential".

As explained [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Analytical_Chemistry/Electrochemistry/Voltaic_Cells/The_Cell_Potential) the battery voltage will be the difference in redox potential between both electrodes, but this also depends on the acid concentration inside your potato, its temperature, and many other factors.

Internal resistance would depend on ion mobility inside a potato.

So it isn't possible to give an exact answer to your question because the characteristics of the potato aren't normalized. However you can use your potato battery to measure the potato characteristics (for example, check that the potato pH correlates with your calculation of cell potential at that pH, etc, which should result in interesting stuff to put in your report).